# Rwanda: renewable ten-year visa vs. permanent

Tags: visa, resident-permit

[Rwandan government](https://www.migration.gov.rw/visa/visitors-visa) (click on V12) mentions a visa for up to ten years in Rwanda, renewable.  Elsewhere there is a mention of a permanent permit.  I haven’t been able to find any info about it.  I’m hesitant to contact DGIE on the chance of creating some prejudice toward me.

Is there anything about a permanent permit that could make it preferable to a renewable long-term visa?

I don’t personally have any plans for a ten-year visit (nor even five) but I don’t like having to watch the calendar and get out after only three months.  Plus, I’m curious about the difference when the lack of detail makes them **seem** effectively the same.

Comment: 10 years is the visa validity, not the duration of stay. Also it's not a residence permit, and work or change of status is not allowed

Comment: I know it doesn't permit work.  Are you saying the "permanent permit" _does_ permit work?  And that the "long-term visitor visa" still only allows short visits?

Comment: Yes to both would be my understanding